# Как написать update с помошью MERGE?

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

Как написать `update` с помошью `MERGE`?

Сейчас имею такой запрос:

```
update dbt
set TYPE_ACCOUNT ='Т'
where ACCOUNTID in (27746, 277744, 206745)
```

, но хочу точно такой же `update`, только с `MERGE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точно такой же `update`, только с `MERGE`:

```
merge into dbt tgt using (
    select 'T' type_account, column_value accountid 
    from sys.odciNumberList (27746, 277744, 206745)
) src on (src.accountid=tgt.accountid)
when matched then update set tgt.type_account=src.type_account  
/
 
3 rows merged.
```